# Android NDK. How to omit path in __FILE__/__BASE_FILE__

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, c-preprocessor

I've searched SO and found that I could use __BASE_FILE__.
The problem I think is that ndk-build calls gcc with the full path to a file and I get that path __BASE_FILE__.
So, the question is how to make ndk-build call gcc at least with a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

the Android NDK building process is based on Makefile/s, download the NDK and take a look at the `docs` folder, especially to `ANDROID-MK.HTML`, you can take a quick tour about the NDK docs folder [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Docs).

Comment: Lol, thank you for your very precise answer. The only more precise answer would be "search the Internet" :)